# Why is the istft(sft(x)) not equal to x

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to reconstruct a signal by doing the inverse short-time fourier transform of a short time fourier transformed signal - similar to that in the scipy tutorial [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.istft.html#scipy.signal.istft)

It seems though that the resulted reconstructed signal is not the same as the original. My code is below

```
import scipy.signal as sig
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 44100
nfft = 2048
time = np.arange(10*fs)/float(fs) # test signal will be 10 seconds long
test_sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 50 * time) # gives 441000 sample vector

f,t,Zxx = sig.stft(test_sig,fs,nfft=2048) # Zxx.shape = (1025,3447)
_, xrec = sig.istft(Zxx,fs) # xrec.shape = 3528704
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong here, it's probably something I'm not understanding about the istft process.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there were a number of things I was missing/misunderstanding about the function arguments in both `sig.stft()` and `sig.istft()`.

The `nfft` argument in `sig.stft()` is if you want to zero-pad the FFT where nfft > nperseg where nperseg is the length of each segment. The default for nperseg in `sig.stft()` is `nperseg = 256`. The default for nfft is `nfft = nperseg`

If using a zero-padded FFT then `sig.istft()` requires nperseg to be specified, which I hadn't done so the default was causing an overestimation in the number of points I was using per segment for the original FFT. The formula it uses if nperseg is not specifed is `nperseg=2*(Zxx.shape[freq_axis] - 1)`. So it assumed that the length of each of my segments was 2*(1025-1) = 2*(1024) = 2048. This corresponds to the initial defaults in `sig.stft()` where `nfft = nperseg` so the default carries through as an assumption to `sig.istft()` unless told otherwise.